# How do I update some information at certain times of the day in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

i have many model in my Django project, I want some of these models that are available to the user with the field to be stored in the database at a certain time after registration.

for example:

We have a form from a model, the user registers this form and I want this form to be saved in my database at a certain time(10 o'clock at night)

How can I program this?

Thanks

Comment: If I am not mistaken you want to use ```crontab```. In Spring Boot there is ```@Scheduled``` annotation that is written on top of any function and given specific time based on your requirement. I think in Django also its ```cron``` functions. After that your function will be executed automatically at given time.

Comment: Instead of delaying the save of something, you could add a time field to the model, marking that it shouldn't be used until a certain time, e.g. 10 o'clock that night

Comment: @Abdusoli I think this solution will work for me,I will give you the result in the next comment, thanks